# Is there an async await method for "simple wait"

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

Say I want to surf the web every 10 minutes.

Basically, I surf the web and then wait 10 minutes.

I want the wait 10 minutes to be async and await. So within those 10 minutes, my program can do other things.

Usually, we use async and await for tasks that took a long time. This time, I just wanna wait a while.

Answer (score 0):

To asynchronously wait, use `Task.Delay`:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```